# Is it OK to use British spelling in answers?

Tags: discussion

Being British, I often write answers with the British spelling of words. Here are some examples:

- Colour (instead of Color)
- Serialise (instead of Serialize)
- Authorisation (instead of Authorization)

Is it "OK" to do this, or should I be using the American English spellings instead? I certainly don't go around editing posts from others to make changes like this, but I've often wondered whether I should try and get into the habit of using z instead of s, etc.

The reason I ask is because the majority of answers use American spelling (which I understand makes perfect sense) - sometimes I include a code sample that naturally uses the American spelling but then I describe what's happening using British spelling (e.g. `AddAuthorization` and then *this adds the authorisation services*). My concern here is that it might be a little confusing and I can't quite gauge that myself, which is why I'm asking for opinions.

Comment: Why wouldn't be ok?

Comment: People get away with much worse than substituting "z" with "s" on SO... I'd think that British English is fine. I've personally never been corrected on here for using it.

Comment: And [from meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Comment: The one in meta.se is even clearer (and includes the distinction about spelling in tags), but we can't mark as a dupe to that one, sadly.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is about whole words. This is about spelling.

Comment: Note that you might simply get corrected because someone might not know the spelling is valid in British English and thinks you've made a spelling mistake.

Comment: y u no speek rite langage? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, British spelling is fine. Your question seems to have some bias. Why ask this and not:

> Is it OK to use American spelling in answers?

Comment: I think the "bias" is down to me *expecting* SO to be American-based in terms of spelling and that British might be "against the norm".

Comment: @KirkLarkin, I've not seen anything, or recall anything, which suggests SO is American-based. (And if it is, it shouldn't be relevant for an international user base.)

Comment: Sure - That's why I emphasised *expecting* in the comment to suggest I wasn't basing that on hard evidence.

Comment: @jpp One might infer the language one should use based on the language of the UI, which uses US instead of UK spelling (e.g. "help center" instead of "help centre"). And the company itself is in the US.

Comment: @Dukeling, The question relates specifically to user content. Certainly, SO's decisions on spelling shouldn't determine your own, provide you abide by the rule "content must be in English".

Comment: I actually expect SO to be an international site, and as such, to not be USA centered. English does not belong to USA.