# Rename [kotlinx.serialisation] to [kotlinx.serialization]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I don't know if it is a typo or just [British English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375196/is-it-ok-to-use-british-spelling-in-answers), but the official name is [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization).

Somebody just created [kotlinx.serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.serialization), so I think 38 questions for [kotlinx.serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.serialisation) should be retagged.
Also, I think the synonum [kotlinx.serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.serialisation) -> [kotlinx.serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx.serialization) can be created to prevent confusion.